# Yield blade file from another file not working

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to display comment index content

```
@section('title', 'Comments')
<a href="{{route('comments.create', ['id'=>$post->id])}}">Create Comment</a>
    @foreach ($comments as $comment)
        @if ($comment->post_id == $post->id)
        <div class="border margin mb-1">
            <div class="border margin">
                <p>{{$comment->text}}</p>
            </div>
            <a href="{{route('comments.edit', $comment->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary float-end">Edit</a>
        </div>
        @endif
    @endforeach
<a href="{{route('posts.show', ['id'=>$post->id])}}">Back</a>
@endsection
```

From posts show file:

```
@extends('layouts.myapp')
@section('content')

<head>
  <link href="{{ asset('css/posts.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<div>
   <h2>Comments</h2>
   <div>
     @include('comments.index')
   </div>
   <a href="{{route('comments.index', ['id' => $post->id])}}">Comments</a>
</div>
<a href="{{route('welcome')}}">Back</a>
@endsection
```

I want to be able to see the comments without having to go on comments.index link, which I have to delete.

Answer (score 0):

It's only a blind guess: maybe you should look at your blade directory structure, where the file with the comments-section is located, maybe it should be

```
@yield('posts.comments')
```

And by the way the `head` tag in the content section looks a bit displaced imho.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not yielding data here. You just include the value here. So use `@include` in stead of `@yield`. The following code is below:

In comment file :

```
 <a href="{{route('comments.create', ['id'=>$post->id])}}">Create Comment</a>
    @foreach ($comments as $comment)
        @if ($comment->post_id == $post->id)
        <div class="border margin mb-1">
            <div class="border margin">
                <p>{{$comment->text}}</p>
            </div>
            <a href="{{route('comments.edit', $comment->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary float-end">Edit</a>
        </div>
        @endif
    @endforeach
<a href="{{route('posts.show', ['id'=>$post->id])}}">Back</a>
```

Now in the From posts show file:

```
    @extends('layouts.myapp')
@section('content')

<head>
  <link href="{{ asset('css/posts.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<div>
   <h2>Comments</h2>
   <div>
     @include('comments')
   </div>
   <a href="{{route('comments.index', ['id' => $post->id])}}">Comments</a>
</div>
<a href="{{route('welcome')}}">Back</a>
@endsection
```

Comment: When I include 'comments' it throws view not found error since index page is under comments folder and asks if there is such a blade file. But when I include comments.index it throws 'undefined variable $comments'. Do you know what could that be?

Comment: Pass the comment variable in the include.